# Connecting to different schemas using prepared statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have the following code running fine with one sql statement  `selectEmpShowDocs_SQL` referring to `schema1`. In this scenario, I have hard coded the value of `empID` as `2` as shown in the sql below :

```
private String selectEmpShowDocs_SQL = 
            "SELECT " + 
                "emp_doc " +
            "FROM " + 
                "schema1.emp_info " +               
            "WHERE " +              
                "doc_id = ? "+
            "AND"+
                 "empID = 2";
```

Now, I have another sql statement which is retrieving the `emp_id` value and instead of hardcoding the value just like I did above for `empID`, I want to pass the value of `emp_id` obtained from the following sql statement to the above sql statement. This is the statement which is referring to `schema2`.

```
 private String selectEmpIDSQL = 
            "SELECT " + 
                "emp_id " +
            "FROM " + 
                "schema2.emp_id " +             
            "WHERE " +              
                "company_id = 435 "
```

I am wondering is it possible to connect with two different schemas with one prepared statement? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475066/same-prepared-statement-multiple-databases-same-schema) someone mentioned that prepared statement is bound to a specific database and in that case if it's not possible, what would be the best approach for me?

Here is the full code that works fine for me using only the SQL query referring to `schema1`.

```
public List<EmployeeDocument>  getEmployeeDocument(String docId, Integer employeeID) throws DaoException
    {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();                      
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        List<EmployeeDocument> empShowDocs = new ArrayList<EmployeeDocument>();         
        try {
            ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectEmpShowDocs_SQL);
            logger.debug("sql query :" + selectEmpShowDocs_SQL);
            System.out.println(selectEmpShowDocs_SQL);
            pstmt.setString(1, docId);                  
            logger.debug("sql parameters, docId:" + docId);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();          
            while(rs.next()) {              
                EmployeeDocument empShowDocRecord = new EmployeeDocument();     
                empShowDocRecord.setEmp_Content(rs.getString("emp_doc")));  
                empShowDocs.add(empShowDocRecord);
            }
        } catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {                  
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rs = null;
            }
            if (pstmt != null) {
                try {
                    pstmt.close();
                } catch(SQLException sqe) {
                    sqe.printStackTrace();
                }
                pstmt = null;
            } 
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    sqle.printStackTrace();
                }
                conn = null;
            }
            if (ds != null) {               
                ds = null;
            }
        }       
        return empShowDocs;
    }

    private String selectEmpShowDocs_SQL = 
            "SELECT " + 
                "emp_doc " +
            "FROM " + 
                "schema1.emp_info " +               
            "WHERE " +              
                "doc_id = ? "+
            "AND"+
                 "empID = 2";           



    private String selectEmpIDSQL = 
            "SELECT " + 
                "emp_id " +
            "FROM " + 
                "schema2.emp_id " +             
            "WHERE " +              
                "company_id = 435 "
```

Comment: Are your schemas not in the same database? Also, please learn about `try with resources` to clean up your exception handling and resource closing.

Comment: No, they are not in same database. I have different connection parameters for both the schemas. Sure, I will try to learn what you mentioned.

Comment: Why are you getting the `Connection` out of `jdbcTemplate` instead of using `jdbcTemplate` directly? Why are you catching `Throwable`? This is quite horrible code.

Comment: The actual code for some other webservice was written by someone else, so I just followed what they did in this case. Is that stopping me from achieving what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Well no, but it certainly isn't helping you if you throw around that kind of code without understanding what you're doing. You could shrink that code into 10% of what it is now. However you can't do cross database joins (well, generally speaking), so if you really do have 2 separate databases you need to perform two queries.

Comment: Okay, I will probably have two prepared statements and try to perform two queries. When you say 10% of what it is now, you are referring to the code after using `try with resources` right?

Comment: I'm referring to using `JDBCTemplate` properly. It's designed to allow you to execute queries without all the boilerplate, but somehow the person who wrote that code managed to completely bypass that. Then you copied it verbatim and that's how horrible code spreads. I'm also not completely convinced that you have different databases instead of a single database with multiple schemas, but I'll let you sort that out.